# Restore database in mongodb replication

Tags: restore, mongodump, mongorestore

My requirement is to restore mongodb databases from dev box to test server having three nodes. I have setup the replication between three nodes for high availability.
I have created backup on dev using mongodump to a different directory. 
Now my requirement is to restore all databases in test server using copied folder path.

I have looked number of articles over internet but did not find the exact solution to restore databases. I know mongorestore command will work but how to restore from different path. 
I tried following steps to achieve this >
   1. Restore with replication /without replication.
   2. stop mongodb service and copy backup folder to data directory then 
      start service.

Mongo Config Information >

storage:
  dbPath: "E:/AO_DATA/mongodb/data"

systemLog:
  destination: file
  path: "E:/AO_DATA/mongodb/log/mongod.log"

net:
  port: 30198

replication:
  replSetName: "repl_01"

Please help me to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Studio3T](https://studio3t.com/). When you setup your replicaset in this software, you will see your nodes and your collections. Right click on the collection, export & import in your desired format and location.